Are doors to balconies obligated in mezuzot
According to Halacha, does a doorway to a balcony ever need a mezuzah? Or no, is it not considered an obligated dwelling space?

See https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/58984
"There are many poskim who are of the opinion that in a balcony such as you described it is exempt from a Mezuza. This is especially so if the balcony is not enclosed  and if the balcony doesn’t have 4X4 Amot which is approximately 2X2 meters."
(SEE: שו"ת יחוה דעת חלק ד סימן נא, ש"ך יורה דעה סימן רפז ס"ק א)
See also https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/838
Question
Does a balcony require a Mezuzah? Why?
And on which side, does one need to affix it if so?
Answer
In order to place a Mezuza and say the blessing one needs an entrance with a ceiling of the size of two meters by two meters.
Regarding a balcony - if the balcony is a closed one which does not have an exit to a yard, one should place a Mezuzah on the right door post upon entering from the balcony to the house.
If the balcony has an exit to a yard there are different opinions - Harav Kook Zt"l placed a Mezuzah on the right door post (when entering the house). It is advisable to act as is done in the community.
https://dinonline.org/2021/02/10/mezuzah-on-unroofed-balcony/
In general, if the doorway has two doorposts and a lintel it would need a mezuza, If you can send us a picture, I would prefer that, because with Hilchos Mezuza it is best to actually see the doorway in order to prevent mistakes. Regarding the correct side to place the mezuza, with the assumption that it is not possible to get to the balcony from the street, and therefore the only way to enter the balcony is from the apartment, the mezuza would be on the right side of the door when going out to the balcony. If the balcony is smaller than 4×4 amos then the halacha might be different.)
